# Dot product of vectors

Tags: vectors

Given that

$p = \vec{a}$

$q = \vec{b}$

How can I prove that if

$$|p+q|=|p|$$

Then $p \cdot q$ ( dot product ) is always less than or equal to zero.

**My attempt:**

On taking the magnitude of the two sides 
We get either $|q|=0$ 
Or 
$|q|=-2|p|\cos{\theta}$

How can I draw my inferences from this ?

Does this $|q|=-2|p|\cos{\theta}$ lead to any unique conclusions?

Comment: Would [math.se] be a better home for this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your hypothesis implies $|p+q|^2 =|p|^2$, that is $(p+q) \cdot(p+q) = |p|^2$, which can be rephrased as $|p|^2 + |q|^2 + 2 p \cdot q = |p|^2$ because $p\cdot q= q\cdot p$.
Thus $|q|^2 + 2 p \cdot q = 0$. Since $|q|^2 \geq 0$, we conclude that $ p \cdot q \leq 0 $.

Comment: Works too, but you should know the result in second step.

Comment: Better now, nice result.

Comment: Well this would imply that angle between the vectors must be between 90 and 180 degrees .

Comment: Is there a way one can think of it logically ?

Answer (score 0):

Your method does not lead to any conclusion about the dot product.
So try to set arbitrary values to vectors **a** and **b** .
Here is a detailed take.
[image]

Comment: Next time on mathematics like questions please try mathematics stack exchange.

Comment: Thank you for understanding.

Comment: Please use [Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on Physics SE to display mathematical equations and proofs.  It's the site standard.

Comment: Yes noted, it's quite slow though, any tips to work faster on it ?

Comment: Practice.  Lots of practice. :-)  You can also cut and paste quite a lot from line to line usually - so sometimes copy the line and change it, rather than starting each line from scratch.

Comment: Ahh, I understand. Thanks.